# Basic functionalities of QEMU

Tags: c, embedded, qemu

I have been trying to create a new **"Custom machine"** for **QEMU** and trying to understand the code structure of QEMU. There is a lot of help for QEMU's internal code structure like TCG etc.

But I want to understand the functions or inherited functions and syntax used to write a custom machine. For example `SYS_BUS_DEVICE`, what is the definition of this? What are the usages, how to use etc.

I am not sure if my question is even right or SYS_BUS_DEVICE is a user definition.  Can someone clarify this? Or point me to any documentation which describes the custom machine development.

Every time I try to look for such code structure I end up with QEMU internal code. Are they both same? Is definitions like SYS_BUS_DEVICE is internal to QEMU?

Comment: I understand I m asking the question in a very layman language but I mean here the APIs used for easier development.  If that makes the question a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

SYS_BUS_DEVICE is a QOM object used to define devices on a bus. It's part of the object model. What documentation we have for developers can be found at: https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devel/index.html (specifically https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devel/qom.html).